# How do I send a document name to a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to, let's say on index.htm have this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascriptfile.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

and then have that script return `<title>index</title>`, and the index being dynamic according to the file name. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: ...why wouldn't you just render the title in the page to begin with?  This would unnecessarily delay the user's page load.

Comment: Maybe it has to be generated dynamically, based on user input?

Comment: @Jen: doubtful, because the OP said _"...based on the file name."_

Comment: I would recommend against doing this, because it introduces a tight coupling between user-facing content and the server's internal file structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get your filename
var uri = location.href.split("?")[0].split("/");
var filename = uri[uri.length-1];

// get title tag DOMnode
var title = document.getElementByTagName('title')[0];
title.innerText = filename;
```

Answer (score 3):

You should really be doing this server-side.  But if you insist on client-side processing, this should work:

```
document.write('<title>' +
    window.location.pathname.replace(/^(.*\/)?([^\/.]*).*$/, "$2") +
    '</title>');
```

If you do go with this approach, $DEITY will kill a kitten each time someone visits your site.

Comment: even if I answered, +1 for the $DEITY-related joke

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible answers :

- if you know exactly what pages you have and all pages are static html, don't do that kind of thing. Just put the title in the page, you'll avoid useless delay
- in other cases, this is not a job for JS. Use a server-side technology to dynamically create your page.

In short : `dynamic ? use server-side language : put title directly in html`

Answer (score 1):

You should note that the browser doesn't not really know what the file name is. All its knows is its public location (URL). Having this in mind, you can read the URI from `document.location`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location

This property returns a `Location` object:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

The `Location` object has a `pathname` property you can parse.